# Is there ANY relation between Pennsylvania and Transylvania?

Tags: toponymy

Like the title asks, is there ANY relation between Pennsylvania and Transylvania, historically or otherwise, or are the names simply very odd coincidences?

Comment: Try looking up "sylvan". "Transylvania was first referred to in a Medieval Latin document in 1075 as ultra silvam, meaning "beyond the forest" (ultra meaning "beyond" or "on the far side of" and the accusative case of sylva (sylvam) "woods, forest"). Transylvania, with an alternative Latin prepositional prefix, means "on the other side of the woods". Pennsylvania is "Penn's Woods"

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't you have just made this an answer and... _not_ have downvoted me (unless you have a good reason and you're the one who did so)?

Comment: It's really a language question, not a history question.

Comment: To post a question here you must show some "research effort". I upvoted your question against the rules because I found it funny (in the best sense), but a simple Google search would have give you the answer. +1 to @MarkC.Wallace as well.

Comment: There's also the Spotsylvania and Pittsylvania counties according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvania), which also mentions Castlevania and the name Sylvester.

Comment: And Transylvania County, North Carolina. BTW, a LOT of European Transylvanians immigrated to Pennsylvania in the 1890-1930 timeframe. The landscape in western Pennsylvania is very like Transylvania (rolling hills, mountains, deep valleys) and they must have felt very much at home.

Answer (score 10):

Sylvan means "woods.

"Transylvania was first referred to in a Medieval Latin document in 1075 as ultra silvam, meaning "beyond the forest" (ultra meaning "beyond" or "on the far side of" and the accusative case of sylva (sylvam) "woods, forest"). Transylvania, with an alternative Latin prepositional prefix, means "on the other side of the woods". [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transylvania)

Pennsylvania is "Penn's Woods"